# .NET 4 ClickOnce where are images stored after deployment

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, clickonce

I have a .NET 4 WPF app deployed via ClickOnce.

The app itself is located in this folder:

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\20M1K3QV.1J5\YBVR1JRD.ZCH\mana..tion_94f2a286b90217ab_0001.0000_92543ff193690b91
```

In my solution images used by the app are located in a subfolder named Images, in a deployed app folder, however, there is no subfolder Images and I did a full search of the drive and was not able to find a specific image by name anywhere but in the original solution Images folder...

Anyway, my question is where are the images stored after ClickOnce deployement? Are they embedded into the app executable?

Comment: This depends on the build settings of the project.  If they are set to embed as resource (best option) then they will be embedded.  If they are just set to copy to the output folder then I'm not sure what would happen in this caes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the images are embedded in the .exe file, which is correct and recommended. If you want something else you should check the `Build action` and `Copy to Output Directory` settings in the `Properties` tool window for each image.

Comment: Build Action for images is currently "Resource" which is the default because I did not touch that... so if that build action results in embedding the file into the executable, what is the purpose of "Embedded Resource"?

Comment: After some googling looks like in both cases the files are embedded but "Embedded Resource" is for Winforms apps to be used with Resource Manager...

Answer (score 1):

To add to what JaredPar already mentioned if they are set to copy they should create another folder the way you are expecting in your original post.

Most likely they are embedded in your EXE.

[Check this Social.MSDN Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/df6a0707-bbd8-4e7e-b6b6-5b91dacc0468)